# Johansen Cointegration Test

Tags: r, time-series, stata, cointegration

I do have a question regarding Johansen Cointegration test.

After checking my time series variables with ADF, PP and KPSS, I conclude that my time series is **non-stationary at level** but **stationary at first differences**. Thus, the variables are *all* **I(1)**.

Now my question:

When I apply the Johansen cointegration test (function `ca.jo` in "urca" package in R), should I test with the variables at level or at first difference?

I did not test the first differences yet, but I do find at least one cointegration for the level data. I assume it's okay to test with level data as long as the variables have the same order of integration?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you have to supply levels as the main argument for the `ca.jo` function. I believe this question has been asked (and answered) before, you may find it if you search carefully.

Comment: [Here](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/161012/testing-cointegration-at-level-or-with-first-differences/164271#164271) is the duplicate question. However, for some reason I cannot find it when I try to mark the current one as a duplicate. Perhaps it is because the answer to the other question has neither been accepted nor upvoted.

Comment: Indeed, @RichardHardy, you see in the i/f the following when you try to use that as a dup: `This question does not have an upvoted or accepted answer`

Comment: Okay, thank you! In that question, you, Richard, argue that if "the series are trend-stationary, and there is no need to proceed with cointegration analysis." Why is that?